# How dask array chunking works for three or more dimension?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, dask

Consider the following code snippet where I am trying to create a dask array with asymmetric but repeated blocks of size `(3, 4, 5)`:

```
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da
a = np.random.randint(0, 9, (3, 12, 10))
d = da.from_array(a, chunks=(3, 4, 5))
```

The above snippet does not throw any error / warning. But When I try to do the following:

```
r = d.map_blocks(np.sum)
out = r.compute()
```

It throws the error below:

```
python3.7/site-packages/dask/array/core.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   4099 
   4100     while isinstance(arrays, (list, tuple)):
-> 4101         result.append(tuple([shape(deepfirst(a))[dim] for a in arrays]))
   4102         arrays = arrays[0]
   4103         dim += 1

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check `map_block` docs [here](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.map_blocks). Under `chunks` parameter description, it said:

"If not provided the resulting array is assumed to have the same block structure as the first input array."

So your `sum` function should be something like this:

```
def compute_block_sum(block):
    return np.array([[np.sum(block)]])[:,None]
```

Then you do

```
d.map_blocks(compute_block_sum).compute()
```